# Python subprocess: Get environment after subprocess completed

Tags: python, subprocess

We have a tool that comes with a shell script which sets up the environment variables necessary for running the tool. It's fairly convoluted chain of different scripts that determine a bunch of stuff and export/set the env.

We then need that environment every time we want to call the tool itself.

Ideally we would be able to do something like this:

```py
completed_script = subprocess.run("the_settings_script.bat")
[...]
subprocess.run(["some", "other", "call"], env=completed_script.env)
```

That doesn't work obviously. Is there another nice way to get back the environment after running a subprocess? We could of course run the script in every `subprocess.run()` call before the actual tool call, but that is kind of inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no portable way. In any modern OS the parent environment is passed to child processes, but in no way a child can change its parent environment. It used to be possible in good old MS/DOS and only with .com type programs because the address of the parent environment was stored at a well known address in the child process but I know no such tricks for Windows or any Unix-like system.

Here the best way it to setup the environment before starting the Python interpretor. That way the changed environmnent will be passed to all the subprocesses.